# Secrets Mongo docker compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, sh

I've worked in mongo and docker-compose for a while now and I'm noticing an abundance of problems when attempting to add users through compose but as secrets.

The issue I'm facing right now is, I've tried secrets, mongo.init.js/sh files and regular passing of usernames and passwords. Whenever I pass it directly to docker compose as an environment variables it works fine. Mongo.init.js files and sh files just dont work at all an I get errors like `Error saving history file: FileOpenFailed Unable to open() file /home/mongodb/.dbshell: No such file or directory` . I've also tried to add users as `/run/secret/..` but that seems to have no effect (in general mongo.init.js/sh files have 0 effect, the only thing that i've found to be useful are the environment variables in compose).Has anyone found a reliable solution that is secure, because the more I look this up the more errors and problems I find.

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  storing_script:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on: 
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4.8
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/mongo-data:/data/db
      - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: db_username
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: db_password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: log_db
    command: mongod --port 27018
    restart: unless-stopped
    logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
            max-file: "5"
            max-size: "10m"
    secrets:
      - db_password
      - db_username

secrets:
  db_username:
    file: ./db_username.txt
  db_password:
    file: ./db_password.txt
```

Comment: I think anything "init" related is copied into the container during `Dockerfile`, not mounted in `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: @DanielW. but it works when I just insert a string there. Then it takes it and creates the user and password. When I use a secret as explained above it does nothing?

Comment: Im trying this too and coming with the same problem. Currently im doing `cat(_getEnv("MONGO_DB_ADMIN_USERNAME_FILE"));` to fetch my secret. I get this error `uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: Error preflighting normalization: U_STRINGPREP_PROHIBITED_ERROR : (...)`
Would you care to upload your entrypoint file too?

Comment: @DanielW. That's false. It can be copied from within the Dockerfile (build), but also done like this by mouting it. It's essentially exectly the same as copying it.